# ExpressionEngine simple search and special characters

Tags: simple-search

How can I make sure that special characters like å, æ, ø, will be noticed while searching for content on a webpage. Im not getting any results when searching words which contain these characters. The site is in Norwegian. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What version of ExpressionEngine are you currently running?

Comment: Hi, Im using v. 6.4.3

Comment: The fields containing the characters are also in a Wygwam fieldtype. Could this be the issue?